# Given an integer N. What is the smallest integer greater than N in java

Tags: java

I was trying to write a code that takes an integer between 1 and 1_000_000 and gives back the smallest integer greater than that with the same digits, and if it doesn't exist, it prints 0.

For example

input: 156

output 165

input 330

output 0

input 27711

output 71127

My problem is, my code below doesn't return the correct output for other inputs.

For example, in input 4231, the output should be 4312.

I'm having trouble finding the best algorithm that returns the correct output for every input.

tnx in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = sc.nextLine();
    char[] chars = new char[x.length()];
    char[] oldChars = new char[x.length()];


    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        chars[i] = x.charAt(i);
        oldChars[i] = chars[i];
    }


    if (x.length() > 3){
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length(); j++) {      
            if (chars[0] < chars[j]) {
                temp = chars[0];
                chars[0] = chars[j];
                chars[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 1; j <= x.length() ; j++) {           
            for (int i = 1; i < x.length() - 1; i++) {
                if (chars[i] > chars[i+1]){
                    temp = chars[i];
                    chars[i] = chars[i+1];
                    chars[i+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
        }
    }
    
    else if (x.length() == 1)
        System.out.println(0);

    else {
            temp = chars[x.length()-2];
            chars[x.length()-2] = chars[x.length()-1];
            chars[x.length()-1] = temp;
            if (chars[x.length()-2] > oldChars[x.length()-2])
                for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(chars[i]);
                }
            else
                System.out.println(0);
    }
    

    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: `n + 1` seems sufficient. You may be describing your problem incorrectly--do you mean "the smallest integer that can be made from the digits in `n`"?

Comment: The smallest integer greater than 156 is 157.  There are conditions to your question that you are not telling us.  You need to edit your question.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I mean with the same digits! I edited the question.

Comment: Better description: `for input N, find the smallest integer between N and 1,000,000 using the same digits in N`

Comment: Not the most efficient solution, but you can create a for loop from N + 1 to 1_000_000 and check if each index contains the same digits as the input in a different order.  Break the loop on the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

- Starting with the least `N` significant digits. `N` starts with `2`. Save a copy.
- then create all permutations of those `N` digits.
- join them into a String and put in a `TreeMap<String>`
- if there exists a next higher value of the original `N` digits, return the new value
  with the new ending concatenated to the original.
- else, increase `N` by one and repeat the process.

```
public class NextLargestInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Generate 10 random numbers.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          int val = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          System.out.printf("%-12s   %-12s%n",val,nextHighest(Integer.toString(val)));
        }
```

Prints something like

```
1446553155     1446553[515]
1801279982     18012[82799]
1894877459     18948774[95]
805018669      8050186[96] 
521703779      5217037[97] 
1926164416     19261644[61]
1236907656     12369076[65]
1326860288     1326860[828]
1049149602     10491496[20]
1516995584     1516995[845]
```

The brackets on the right show what endings were permuted to get the minimum

The primary method.

```
    public static String nextHighest(String e) {
        char[] digits = e.toCharArray();
        // start two digits from the end
        int i = digits.length - 2;
        // tree set to store the permuted strings
        NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        for (; i >= 0; i--) {
            
            // the last N digits
            char[] shortList =
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(digits, i, digits.length);

            // save a copy of the original N digit ending
            String originalTail = new String(shortList);

            permute(shortList, digits.length - i, set);
            
            // get the next higher ending from the set
            String minTail = set.higher(originalTail);
            // if it exists, return the value.
            if (minTail != null) {
                String head =
                        new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(digits, 0, i));
                return String.format("%s[%s]", head, minTail);
            }
            // clear the set and try a larger ending.
            set.clear();
        }
        // no success, return the original value.
        return e;
    }
```

Utility method to permute the character array

```
    public static void permute(char[] elements, int length,
            Set<String> vals) {
        if (length == 1) {
            vals.add(new String(elements));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                permute(elements, length - 1, vals);
                if (length % 2 == 1) {
                    swap(elements, 1, length - 1);
                } else {
                    swap(elements, i, length - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Utility method to swap array elements.

```
    public static void swap(char[] list, int i, int j) {
        char temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete and accurate explanation. You really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, please

```
int muldigits(int n){

    int result = 0;

    String [] strings = String.valueOf(Math.abs(n)).split("(?!^)");
    List<Integer> intsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : strings) {
        intsList.add(Integer.parseInt(string));
    }

    if(n<0){
        Collections.sort(intsList);
        String temp = Arrays.toString(intsList.toArray()).replace(", ", "");
        System.out.println(temp);
        result = - Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(1, temp.length()-1));
    }else{
        Collections.sort(intsList, Collections.reverseOrder());
        String temp = Arrays.toString(intsList.toArray()).replace(", ", "");
        result = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(1, temp.length()-1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. I tried this code but it doesn't return the correct answer for different inputs. In order to thank you for your kindness in helping me, I give you an upvote. Tnx again.

Comment: Thx. Could you give me the different inputs where this code fails ?

Comment: You can test it yourself with different inputs. Your code just reverses the number, for example for input 156 your code return 651, but the correct output is 165. Or for input 330 your code must return 0, but it returns 330 and etc. The point is, we want the **smallest** integer greater than N.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use apache commons collections4 and performance does not matter you can use something like that:

```
package test;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NextNumberCalculator {
    public int calculateNearest(int input) {
        List<Character> inputChars = String.valueOf(input).chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return CollectionUtils.permutations(inputChars)
                .stream()
                .mapToInt(chars -> Integer.parseInt(StringUtils.join(chars, "")))
                .filter(permutation -> permutation > input)
                .min()
                .orElse(0);
    }
}
```

Here some unit test:

```
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class NextNumberCalculatorTest {
    private NextNumberCalculator calculator;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        calculator = new NextNumberCalculator();
    }
    
    @Test
    void calculateNearest() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(165, calculator.calculateNearest(156));
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, calculator.calculateNearest(330));
        Assertions.assertEquals(71127, calculator.calculateNearest(27711));
        Assertions.assertEquals(414, calculator.calculateNearest(144));
    }
}
```